# Python – hashlib.blake2b-256/512?

Tags: python, cryptography, hashlib

I often see references to multiple types of `blake2b`– a 256-bit version, a 512-bit version, and so on. What version is `hashlib.blake2b()`? I don't see any mentions of it.

```
hashlib.blake2b(data=b'', *, digest_size=64, key=b'', salt=b'', person=b'', fanout=1, depth=1, leaf_size=0, node_offset=0, node_depth=0, inner_size=0, last_node=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.blake2b)

```
hashlib.blake2b(data=b'', *, digest_size=64, key=b'', salt=b'', person=b'', fanout=1, depth=1, leaf_size=0, node_offset=0, node_depth=0, inner_size=0, last_node=False)
```

The default `digest_size` is 64 bytes (512 bits)